# Google Analytics: Method for viewing "real time" users from multiple websites in a single GA account.

Tags: google-analytics

I'm tracking the real-time performance of several websites in GA. Each has its own GA statistics and real-time view. I'd like to have one GA# that tracks the combined "real-time" users on all websites.

Is this possible? If yes, please advise.

Thank you!

```
Real-Time#'s      Tracked TLD          GA#
-----------        --------         ---------
    50             web1.com         GA#123456
   100             web2.com         GA#654321
   400             web3.com         GA#789456
   200             web4.com         GA#987654

             *Combined GA Account*

Real-Time#'s      Tracked TLD          GA#
-----------        --------         ---------
   750        web1.com, web2.com    GA#159753
              web3.com, web4.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google offers developers an analytics API. The analytics API allows you to fetch data for real time. You can combine the json results for all of your sites and fetch it with AJAX on a 1-5 second time delay.

Analytics API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/

Real Time Analytics API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/

Real Time Analytics Code Examples: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get#examples

Get your Analytics API key and try it here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/analytics.googleapis.com/

Comment: thanks for the info! I'm not really a 'developer', but more of a web publisher. I get 99% of my coding knowledge from StackOverflow and the other 1% from trial and error. Can you please direct me to a tutorial or resource for this?

Comment: Links added Mr. B